# The pronunciation of final "s"

Tags: pronunciation, orthography

(First question ever.)

Fellow friends,

I've stumbled upon a weird quirk in this language whose spelling-pronunciation correspondence at times works in mysterious ways.

How am I to know for sure when the final [s] in English words is to be pronounced /s/ or /z/? For instance, "house" (as a noun) is pronounced with an unvoiced /s/ at the end, whereas the verb with the same spelling has a voiced /z/ sound in the same place. Yet words like "pause" seem to retain the /z/ sound; and "increase" keeps its /s/ (only changing the stress), regardless of their role as nouns or verbs.

I have attempted to find an answer elsewhere but my quest so far has not come to fruition.

I fear that, as with many aspects of this language, it needs to be memorized by heart. If it is so, can anyone be so kind as to send me a link to some sort of list? Or at least a resource with some guidelines to predict the pronunciation changes?.

I humbly await your response.

Comment: Houses the noun and houses the verb are pronounced the same way.

Comment: @Lambie: yes, but the verb form can be pronounced with either "z" or "s".  And, to make matters worse, the plural for "house" can be pronounced either way as well!  It is only the singular form of house which demands a final "s" and the simple present tense of the verb house which demands a final "z".

Comment: They are both pronounced the same way in AmE if there is an s on the end.

Comment: My experience with AME is the noun takes "s"  and generally takes "z" as a verb, as does housing.

Comment: "If it is so, can anyone be so kind as to send me a link to some sort of list?" http://www.dictionary.com/

Comment: Sorry, Diego A, English is not a phonetic language. That means that even though native speakers grow up with *suggestions* learned at their mothers' knees, there are no real *rules* about how any spelling should be sounded.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't any good rule as far as I know for whether "-se" after a vowel is pronounced as /z/ or /s/ (["-se" after a consonant is almost always /s/, with only a few exceptions like *cleanse*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30195/when-to-pronounce-s-as-z-in-the-middle-of-words/82435#82435)).

Nouns, verbs and adjectives spelled with "-se" may end in either /s/ or /z/. As you have observed, there are some noun-verb pairs where the noun has /s/ and the verb has /z/ (e.g. "excuse") but this is not a consistent pattern, even for words that come in such pairs: "base" is pronounced with /s/ as both a noun and a verb, and "pose" is pronounced with /z/ as both a noun and a verb. (A side note: some noun-verb pairs have a spelling change as well as a pronunciation change, like *advice/advise* and *device/devise*.)

#### Nouns

Nouns with the "-Vse" spelling pattern seem to me to be almost evenly split, or maybe even a bit more likely to have /z/ than /s/: we have /s/ in *abuse base caboose case chase crease dose excuse goose grease grouse house lease louse moose mouse noose release use* and *vise* (a US variant spelling of *vice,* in the sense "clamp") and /z/ in *applause bruise cause cheese clause cruise demise disease disguise ease fuse guise hose muse noise nose pause phase phrase poise pose praise prose raise rise rose ruse surprise tease.* A few "-Vse" nouns can be pronounced with either /s/ or /z/: *spouse, blouse,* and *vase.*

#### Verbs

There are more "-Vse" verbs ending in /z/ (like *braise lose choose diffuse infuse peruse amuse devise advise revise comprise rise arise excise close transpose propose expose impose oppose please ease appease cause (a)rouse*) than there are ending in /s/ (*chase debase encase/incase cease release  crease grouse loose*) but either sound is possible. A few verbs can be pronounced with either /s/ or /z/: *erase douse dowse grease.*

In British English, the spelling *-se* is used for more verbs than in American English. The verb *practise* (American English *practice*) corresponds to the noun *practice* and is typically pronounced the same, despite the spelling difference: /ˈpræktɪs/, with /s/. Verbs ending in the suffix *-ise,* such as *realise* (American English *realize*) are pronounced with /z/.

#### Adjectives

For adjectives with the spelling "Vse", /z/ occurs in *wise,* but I think most others have /s/ (like *loose close obtuse diffuse obese concise*).

I wasn't aware of this before Mitch left a comment, but apparently adjectives ending in the suffix *-ese* (such as *Japanese, Portuguese*) can be pronounced with either /s/ or /z/.

The Oxford English Dictionary says that adjectives ending in the suffix *-ose* also show some variation between /s/ and /z/: "The traditional pronunciation has /s/, but /z/ is frequently heard in the commoner words of this type, especially where the stress is not on the termination."

Additionally, there are some adjectives from nouns ending in *-se* /z/ that also end in /z/: *rose* and *turquoise*.

Comment: I agree with the general idea 'no good rule', but disagree in a handful of instances: for me, 'spouse', 'erase', 'douse', 'Portuguese' only /s/, 'dowse' only /z/.